# How to stop back press button from going back to each fragment that was opened in the activity?

Tags: android, fragment

I am using this to launch a new fragment depending on the screen size of the device.

```
FragmentManager fragMgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
        releaseInfoFragment release = (releaseInfoFragment)fragMgr.findFragmentById(R.id.release);

            release = releaseInfoFragment.newInstance(url);
            FragmentTransaction xaction = fragMgr.beginTransaction();
            xaction.replace(R.id.release, release)
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
    }
```

The problem is when the user presses the back press button, the it goes back to each fragment that was opened during the activities life cycle. How can i make it where it doesnt do this? I just want it to remove the fragment once its pressed the first time, and then go back to the following activity on the second click.

How do i go about doing this?

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to go back through every Fragment, remove `addToBackStack(null)` from your transaction. The function call `addToBackStack(null)` is an instruction to add the Fragment to the back stack.

**EDIT**

I don't know of any simple way to remove all the Fragments from the back stack. Of the top of my head, I suggest this:

1. Leave the call to `addToBackStack(null)` in so that all Fragments are added to the back stack
2. Override your Activity's `onBackPressed()` method and use `popBackStack()` to pop all the Fragments

Looking at the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) for `popBackStack()`, it looks like there are a couple of nice features that can help you:

> POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE: Flag for popBackStack(String, int) and popBackStack(int, int): If set, and the name or ID of a back stack entry has been supplied, then all matching entries will be consumed until one that doesn't match is found or the bottom of the stack is reached.

and

> popBackStack(int id, int flags)
>   Pop all back stack states up to the one with the given identifier.

Comment: That fixed the issue but the only problem is now that the backpress now doesnt just remove the current fragment, it exits the whole activity to the previous activity. I just want it to remove the fragment in the left portion of the screen that is launched when a item is clicked. And then once its clicked again. it leaves the activity.

Comment: I want to check I understand: You want it to remove all the Fragments from the Activity when you click back, and then go back to the previous Activity when you click back again?

Comment: Correct i have a listFragment on the left, on the right the fragments with details are loaded. On backpress i want to remove the fragments from the left Details fragment, and then when it is clicked again, it goes to the previous activity.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want addToBackStack(null) for adding 2nd detail fragment, but not having addToBackStack(null) for adding 1st list fragment. Do you have addToBackStack(null) on 1st FragmentTransaction?

Comment: use "add comment" instead of asking a question via the "Your Answer" and you'll start getting more upvotes...but it seems like you already figured that out!

Answer (score 0):

in my app contest i had the same problem on pressing back i was moving to previous fragment.
But i want to close app on back press, so what i did is .

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
   // super.onBackPressed();
}
```